# Copy values to new sheet after the last sheet and delete column b if empty

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy only the values (not formulas) of the last sheet of any workbook I run the macro on (I won't know the names of sheets or quantity of sheets) and to delete the B column if it's blank and name this new wirksheet "Games". This is what I have and it's not working =(. Could anyone give me a help?

```
Sub ArrumarTabela()
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Cells.Copy

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Games"
    Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ActiveSheet.Name = "Games"

    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In Range("$B$2:$B" & Range("$B$65536").End(xlUp).Row)
        If cl = "" Then cl.EntireColumn.Delete
    Next cl

    Range("C1").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.CutCopyMode = False` This will clear the clipboard... So how will you paste?

Comment: As sid said. You should remove the `cutcopymode = false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this modification do what you need?

```
Sub ArrumarTabela()
    ActiveSheet.Copy 'this will create a new workbook and a new sheet with current

    With ActiveSheet
        .Name = "Games" 'change new sheets name

        .Cells.Copy 'copy all cells
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'paste only values
        .ScreenUpdating = False

        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'last row?

        Set cl = .Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Find("", lookat:=xlWhole) 'find a blank cell in a range

        If Not cl Is Nothing Then cl.EntireColumn.Delete 'delete column if blank exists

        .Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert 'insert new column belfore column C

        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```